# How to find web element with Selenium Python while iterating through URLs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I need to loop through and scrape one element (identical in class name for all the pages) from one million webpages. I have set up the code in the following (simplified) way:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
detail_dict = {}
for i in range(1000000):
    url = f'http://www.cnappc.it/risultato.aspx?IDAssociato={i}&tipo=1#edit'
    driver.get(url)
    elem_detail = wait.until(expected_conditions
                             .presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'content')))
    detail_dict[i] = elem_detail.text
```

The code runs rather smoothly and, when I interrupt the kernel to check, I notice the `i` and `url` increasing for each iteration. However, the driver webpage gets 'stuck' on the very first URL, i.e. http://www.cnappc.it/risultato.aspx?IDAssociato=0&tipo=1#edit, thus `elem_detail.text` returns the same string over and over. It seems as if though the driver webpage cannot keep up with the `driver.get(url)` method, despite the fact that `.get()` waits for the page to load fully.

From [Selenium-Python/Getting Started](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html):

> The driver.get method will navigate to a page given by the URL. WebDriver will wait until the page has fully loaded (that is, the “onload” event has fired) before returning control to your test or script.

I inserted an expected condition for `elem_detail`, to no avail. Setting a `time.sleep(2)` after `driver.get(url)` allows for the driver webpage to change and display different content, but then I would face a major slowdown. Even then, the page would get stuck from time to time, and dictionary value entries end up repeating unsystematically.

Would you be able to reccommend a robust approach which does not involve `time.sleep()`?

---

FYI: I am using selenium with geckodriver.

Comment: You have given the timeout as 10 , try using a try catch block with exceptions , Something like this try:
    # Wait as long as required, or maximum of 10 sec for alert to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(cond.alert_is_present())

 obj = driver.switch_to.alert
except (NoAlertPresentException, TimeoutException) as py_ex:
    print("Alert not present")
    print (py_ex)
    print (py_ex.args)
finally:
    driver.quit() , This would help us to find what is going wrong in the each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @redhatvicky. With reference to the code I posted, should I insert the try/except/finally you suggest after the `driver.get(url)` command?

Comment: Every Code should be inside the try block , So that the expected exception occurs it gets caught and we can see what's happening at what iteration , either the time out issue happens or else any other exception occurs

Comment: Thanks @redhatvicky, I followed your instructions and the result was the following: Alert not present \n Message: \n ('', None, None). I have never encountered an alert on the webpages and my code runs without errors (aside from a few TimeoutException every once in a while [usually hundreds of iterations take place before I reach such an error]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue switching to `webdriver.Chrome()`. The webdriver actually waits for each page to load, searches the class element and moves on to the next page, without specifying any `time.sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax, you code doesnt work for me (python 2.7)

```
for i in range(1000000):
    url = "http://www.cnappc.it/risultato.aspx?IDAssociato=%s&tipo=1#edit" %i
    print("Get url >> %s" %url) #Just for debug and get output
    driver.get(url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    elem_detail = ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wonka! My problem persists: even with your syntax, `elem_detail.text` returns the string of the very first url I pass to the `driver.get(url)` method and will not change for each iteration.

Comment: With seleneium, always works to set sleep time after each interaction, try new edit

Comment: Also, i look up it again, declare wait each time in loop

Comment: Another advice, detail_dict[i] is using to loop variable!! at last run you will acces a list with 1000000-1 items. I cant acces website, but that looks bad. use i to iterate urls (bad idea on your way to hardcode iterate from 1 to 1000000...)

Comment: Thanks Wonka. I agree with you that sleep time works (I mention that myself in the question), but I am trying to restrict waiting times to the absolute necessary, so I am hoping for a solution which does not impose a sleep time (also specified in the question).

As for your last remark, the code I posted is simplified. In reality, I impose a condition for which my dictionary should only gather around 250k keys. But thanks for the thought.

Comment: Check my code again, have to declare wait object each time. Forgot about sleep @GabrieleGilmozzi

Comment: Thank you, forgot to address that point: I tried what you suggested, but the problem persists.